# Installed Ubuntu on another drive, got rid of the drive, and dual boot screen is still coming up

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uninstall

EDIT: I am not asking how to uninstall Ubuntu. The drive it was installed on is now gone. I did not uninstall it before I pulled it out. On start up the dual boot screen is still showing up and asking me to pick between windows or ubuntu.

A while ago I installed Ubuntu on a separate HDD (dual boot with windows 7). Recently I removed the drive from my computer to put in a different computer. How do I uninstall the rest of Ubuntu? It is still showing Ubuntu as an option on the start up dual boot screen.

Comment: Please clarify if you are dual-booting with windows. If yes, this question has been answered. Please use the search function.

Comment: I believe grub installs itself in the mbr of whichever hard drive boots first. Using the fixmbr tool in windows rescue disk should fix this. I don't know the exact steps, hence this is a comment.